# EF6 One to Many and Many to One between same entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a double relationship. Lets say its a Team and Players - a Team has many Players but only one captain

```
    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public Player Captain { get; set; }
        public int CaptainId { get; set; }
    }


    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Players")]
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
        public int TeamId { get; set; }
    }
```

When running update-database this is resulting in an error along the lines of 
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Teams_dbo.Players_TeamId". The conflict occurred in database "dev", table "dbo.Players", column 'Id'. (I'm translating from my real classnames/fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly describe your entity relationship using the Fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(t => t.Players).WithRequired(p => p.Team).HasForeignKey(p => p.TeamId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasRequired(t => t.Captain).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.CaptainId);
```

You can see above that the Team->Captain relationship is treated as a many-to-one. Presumably a given player can't be captain of more than one team, but since the Team->Player relationship is one-to-many, a given player isn't on more than one team anyway and it should be easy to ensure through your UI that a team's captain is also a player for that team and thus a given player will only be captain for one team.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if this is possible with Annotations? (and I agree that this example allows odd things: its a hugely simplified example)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use annotations so I can't really say. The Fluent API allows me to be much more expressive and explicit in describing relationships so I stick to that.