# EF6 Code First confusion when having 2 properties using the same entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm creating my database using the Code First approach which is working perfectly so far. However I have a minor issue which EF6 somehow can't seem to fathom or I'm doing it wrong.

I have class `Project` which has a property `CreatedBy` of type `Person` and another property `Members` of type `ICollection<Person>`;

```
public class Project
{
    // ...
    public Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
}
```

In class `Person` I have added the following property:

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

To tell EF6 that there is supposed to be a Many-to-Many relationship between the 2 classes.

If I run a `Add-Migration`and `Update-Database` in Visual Studio with `CreatedBy` commented out in the `Project` class, what will happen is that a `Project <-> Person` table will be created in the database.

If I then uncomment the `CreatedBy` property and run the same scripts again the `Project <-> Person` table gets deleted and both `Project` and `Person` tables get a new column with a ForeignKey between the two changing it to a 1-to-1 relationship.

How can I, using Code First, set up a relationship between my `Project` and `Person` class so I can how both a 1-to-Many (1 person can create many projects) and a Many-to-Many (many persons can be added to many projects)?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763538/ef6-one-to-many-and-many-to-one-between-same-entities to see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Fluent API for configuration entity:

```
    class ProjectConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
    {
        public ProjectConfiguration()
        {
            HasRequired(e => e.CreatedBy).WithMany(); // one-to-many
            HasMany(e => e.Members).WithMany(); //many-to-many
        }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectConfiguration());
        }
    }
```

More detail about the Fluent API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620

Comment: So if I implement this and run `Add-Migration` EF will look on this an figure not to change my initial setup to 1-to-1 relationships?

Comment: Yes. It all depends on whether you want to change the one-to-one relationship. If you want to not change one-to-one relationship then use the configuration that I described in the answer. If you want to change one-to-one relationship then: HasRequired(e => e.CreatedBy).WithRequiredPrincipal() or HasRequired(e => e.CreatedBy).WithRequiredDependent() - this is configuration one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this, but if you specify and explicit foreign key for your Created by, it should be enough to differentiate the two different relationships:

```
// make nullable if CreatedBy is not required
[ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
public int CreatedById { get; set; }
public Person CreatedBy { get; set; }
```